# Nothing writing to a file in c

Tags: c, file

Printing in two different files using the same code for both the files.
Nothing is being written in the second file(my_rank1.out) whereas in the other file, everything is properly written

```
  FILE *my_pointer; 
  FILE *my_rank_ptr;
  for(int name = 1;name<=5;name++)
  {
      //read(name)
      char filename[21];
      sprintf(filename, "port%d.out", name);

      char temp_file[21];
      sprintf(temp_file, "my_rank%d.out", name);


      my_rank_ptr = fopen(temp_file,"w");
      my_pointer = fopen(filename,"w");


      fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "lambda\tcrossprob\tmutprob\tbasic_seed\trun\tseed\t");
      for(int i=1;i<=nstock;i++)
      {
        fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "var%d\t",i);
      }
      fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "fitness value\n"); 



      fprintf(my_pointer, "lambda\tcrossprob\tmutprob\tbasic_seed\trun\tseed\t");
      for(int i=1;i<=nstock;i++)
      {
        fprintf(my_pointer, "var%d\t",i);
      }
      fprintf(my_pointer, "fitness value\n");

//Some code follows this
      fclose(my_pointer);
      fclose(my_rank_ptr);

}
```

Comment: read() is not a standard c function, we need to know your environment and all functions that you are writen and use.

Comment: Not working even after commenting read()

Comment: You're not checking for errors when opening the files. That would be a good place to start. Likewise with the writes.

Answer (score 0):

Add after every

```
fprintf(my_rank_ptr ....
```

a

```
fprintf(my_pointer
```

as you want to write to two files the same stuff

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, are you checking the output of your `fopen` statement?

```
...
my_rank_ptr = fopen(temp_file,"w");
if(!my_rank_ptr) return -1;
my_pointer = fopen(filename,"w");   
if(!my_pointer) return -1;
...
```

If your FILE pointers are not NULL, then for simplicity you could
arrange all your printf statements to use the same loop:

```
      fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "lambda\tcrossprob\tmutprob\tbasic_seed\trun\tseed\t");
      fprintf(my_pointer, "lambda\tcrossprob\tmutprob\tbasic_seed\trun\tseed\t");
      for(int i=1;i<=nstock;i++)
      {
        fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "var%d\t",i);
        fprintf(my_pointer, "var%d\t",i); 
      }
      fprintf(my_rank_ptr, "fitness value\n");
      fprintf(my_pointer, "fitness value\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting a permission error when trying to open the file for writing. You should always check if the fopen() call succeeded or not before trying to write to a file.

```
     my_rank_ptr = fopen(temp_file,"w");
```

if ( !my_rank_ptr ) // failed to open...